# If block not being evaluated in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am trying to render a list of items using ListView like so:

views.py

```
class EventView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'timer/index.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        events = Event.objects.order_by('-day')[:7]
        return events
```

`events` is then passed to index.html like so:

index.html

```
{% block content %}
    {% if events %}
        <ul>
        {% for event in events %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'timer:detail' event.id %}"></a>>{{ event }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        No events to show
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

The challenge is that the else block is always returned.

I made sure that I have objects in my db and they are never returned. What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the context object, so:

```py
class EventView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'timer/index.html'
    queryset = Event.objects.order_by('-day')[:7]
    context_object_name = 'events'
```

It does not matter what variable name you use in `get_queryset`. It is passed to the template as `object_list`, and as the name specified in the [**`context_object_name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.context_object_name). If you do not specify such attribute, it will use `modelname_list`.